# unable to connect to local server on port 57001 with RHEL 7.2

Tags: ubuntu, rhel, rhel7

I am running a vmware instance of RHEL 7.2 and serving an API on port 57001 which i cannot seem to access from the host machine. Accessing from within the vmware instance works fine.

I have the same exact instance on Ubuntu 15 and 16 and both connect fine to the below URL from both local instance and host machine.

IP ADDRESSES

- HOST: 172.30.20.235
- RHEL: 172.30.18.170
- UBUNTU: 172.30.18.174

Example URL **that works** in local vmware and from host
http://172.30.18.**174**:57001/api/v1/getGradeDistribution

Example URL that **does not work** from host but does work from within vmware
http://172.30.18.**170**:57001/api/v1/getGradeDistribution

Initially for RHEL server I could not even access port 80 from the host but after some digging around I managed to overcome this using the following command:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

I did not have to do this on the Ubuntu servers as I was able to connect to the webserver on port 80 from the host without any hassles.

As far as I can tell the settings are identical across all servers

**Ubuntu 15/16 -- connects to 57001 fine both locally and from host**

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38760         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11335/uwsgi     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3594/beam       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57001           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11335/uwsgi     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3354/redis-server 1
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4369            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3347/epmd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5501/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7884/postgres   
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      3594/beam       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      3625/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::4369                 :::*                    LISTEN      3347/epmd
```

**Red Hat Enterprise 7.2 -- cannot connect to 57001 from host but works locally**

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57001           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15220/uwsgi         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      36289/redis-server  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:44492         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15220/uwsgi         
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1995/dnsmasq        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1510/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1512/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15885/postgres      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1936/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      15296/httpd         
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1510/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1512/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      15885/postgres      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1936/master
```

Any suggestions on how i might be able to make port 57001 reachable from the host for RHEL instance?

**UPDATE**

I just tried this command and the entry was added but it didnt seems to work either :(
`sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=57001/tcp`

Answer (score 0):

sorry for what seems to be a waste of your time for posting this.. i was just able to resolve this by reloading the firewall after adding in the entries! sorry i am completely new to RHEL and wrapping my head around the differences.

**Reload Firewall**

`firewall-cmd --reload`

**or disable it complete:**

`systemctl disable firewalld`